# SSL connection issues between go Scratch container and PG container. How to resolve?

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, docker-compose, go-gorm

### UPDATE

I believe I resolved this issue with this connection...

```
db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", "host='postgres'&user:docker&port=5432&dbname='docker'&password='password'&sslmode=disable")
```

---

I am getting a connection refused between a Docker PG container and a GoLang Scratch container. The error is:

```
============   exiting ==========
todo_1      | pq: SSL is not enabled on the server
todo_1      | panic: failed to connect database e
```

[The docker-compose.yml file](https://github.com/vinceyoumans/achal/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)

[The main.go file which is panicking](https://github.com/vinceyoumans/achal/blob/master/go_amex/main.go)

[Complete code base with Docker files](https://github.com/vinceyoumans/achal)

OTHER NOTE:

- I am using GORM library to connect with PG.

REQUEST:
Please look over code and give some hints on where and how to resolve this SSL issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL is not enabled on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959148/ssl-is-not-enabled-on-the-server)

Comment: You _must_ put the relevant code in your question. Links are great for added detail, but a question must be complete on its own.

Comment: Your docker-compose.yml file has not provide settings to Postgres with any allowing remote connections.
See https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/01/23/configure-postgresql-to-allow-remote-connection.html

Answer (score 3):

You can follow the code to find the documentation on how to use the Postgres calls.

- github.com/jinzhu/gorm calls
- database/sql which calls
- lib/pq

And lib/pq [documents it's usage](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq) including:

> - dbname - The name of the database to connect to
> - user - The user to sign in as
> - password - The user's password
> - host - The host to connect to. Values that start with / are for unix   domain sockets. (default is localhost)
> - port - The port to bind to. (default is 5432)
> - sslmode - Whether or not to use SSL (default is require, this is not   the default for libpq)
> - fallback_application_name - An application_name to fall back to if one isn't provided.
> - connect_timeout - Maximum wait for connection, in seconds. Zero or   not specified means wait indefinitely.
> - sslcert - Cert file location. The file must contain PEM encoded data.
> - sslkey - Key file location. The file must contain PEM encoded data.
> - sslrootcert - The location of the root certificate file. The file   must contain PEM encoded data.

And:

> - disable - No SSL
> - require - Always SSL (skip verification)
> - verify-ca - Always SSL (verify that the certificate presented by the   server was signed by a trusted CA)
> - verify-full - Always SSL (verify that the certification presented by   the server was signed by a trusted CA and the server host name
>     matches the one in the certificate)

So your connect string for a database without SSL is simply:

```
db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", "host='postgres' port=5432 user=docker dbname='docker' password='password' sslmode=disable")
```

Or you could configure Postgres with an SSL key. That's less trivial, but to implement you'd need to modify the postgresql.conf file to enable the ssl settings and mount the TLS key pair as a volume, or preferably a secret with swarm mode. One of the many examples of how to do this can be found at: https://gist.github.com/likwid/86193ef581c530ea55d3

Comment: Any benefit of enabling SSL if the database container is not exposed? It should be pretty safe staying in the default bridge network.

Comment: @FranklinYu That depends on your local environment and what attacks you want to defend against. If containers are deployed on different hosts using overlay networking without IPSec configured, then there's a network sniffing risk. Otherwise, I believe most do not encrypt since any attacks I can think of would already have root access to the host.